# Timeout when attempting to retrieve data extensions

Tags: rest-api, dataextensions, python

I am new to working with the FuelSDK Python API but I am puzzled by my initial attempts at using it.

First, I tried getting content area objects using the steps described here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/content-areas/content-area-retrieve.html#pythonpost

And everything works great! The output from my putty session:

```
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 ~]$ cd experiments/python/FuelSDK-Python/
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 FuelSDK-Python]$ . fuelsdk-env.sh
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 FuelSDK-Python]$ python Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ET_Client
ET_Client.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Import the FuelSDK module instead. This module will be removed in the future.
  warnings.warn('Import the FuelSDK module instead. This module will be removed in the future.', DeprecationWarning)
>>> myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()
>>> contentarea = ET_Client.ET_ContentArea() contentarea .auth_stub = 
>>> myClient results = contentarea.get() print results
<FuelSDK.rest.ET_Get object at 0x208a550>
```

As you can see, I got the results object back and all is great. I also want to get the data extensions. Following the steps described here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extensions/data-extension-retrieve.html#pythonpost

I expected to be able to get  the data extensions. But as you can see from my shell output:

```
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 ~]$ cd experiments/python/FuelSDK-Python/
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 FuelSDK-Python]$ . fuelsdk-env.sh
[gs41380@etmdevx-tools501 FuelSDK-Python]$ python Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ET_Client
ET_Client.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Import the FuelSDK module instead. This module will be removed in the future.
  warnings.warn('Import the FuelSDK module instead. This module will be removed in the future.', DeprecationWarning)
>>> myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()
>>> dataextension = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension() dataextension.auth_stub 
>>> = myClient results = dataextension.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "FuelSDK/rest.py", line 306, in get
    obj = ET_Get(self.auth_stub, self.obj_type, props, search_filter, options)
  File "FuelSDK/rest.py", line 205, in __init__
    response = auth_stub.soap_client.service.Retrieve(ws_retrieveRequest)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 538, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 637, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1198, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error The read operation timed out>
```

The request times out before returning me anything useful. Any idea why this is the case? Thanks in advance,